# Memory Access time in 2 level Paging

Tags: memory-management, paging, tlb

Consider a system with a two-level paging scheme in which a regular memory
access takes 150 nanoseconds, and servicing a page fault takes 8 ms.
An average instruction takes 100 ns of CPU time, and two memory
accesses. The TLB hit ratio is 90%, and the page fault rate is one in every 10,000
instructions. What is the effective average instruction execution time?

This was asked in GATE 2004. To solve the question, I would follow the below concept : 
T(memory access avg) = .90(150) + .1(150+150+150) = 180 
*(150- level1, 150-level2 and 150-memory)* 
T effective = 100+ 2* 180 + 1/10000* 8* 10^6 = 1260.

Is this approach correct ? Also I have the following doubts  :

1. There won't be a page fault when there is a TLB hit because the most
   frequently used pages has to be in the memory. Is it correct ?
2. What is the size of the page table for a process? Say for a 32 bit
   virtual address, for every process do we allocate a page-table with
   2^32 entries ? How is the memory limits managed in paging ?

Please explain theses concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following

[image: 100 + 2*(.1 * 150 + 0.9 * 0 ) + 2*(150+ 8*10^6 * 1/20000 ) = 1230]

here 100ns for instruction execution (no difference of opinion there)

Now given TLB hit ratio is 90%, so whenever there is a TLB miss, we have to do 2 memory accesses, since it is given a 2 level paging scheme.

and irrespective of TLB hit or miss `2*(150+ 8*10^6 * 1/20000 )` should be done which is memory access time for contents and overhead for page fault.

I think your expression assumes, that for an instruction whenever a TLB hit occurs for first content, it follows for the second

so you assume `hit-hit or miss-miss`,while since given TLB hit is 90%(per access and not per instruction), I feel there should be all 4 possible combinations

`hit-hit, miss-miss, hit-miss,miss-hit`

Comment: 2*(150+ 8*10^6 * 1/20000 ) is it always independent of TLB hit ? That is the second part of the question. Here the data is given explicitly. But does it always hold ? Page fault can't happen on a TLB miss is my assumption.

Comment: are you sure, you wanted to say TLB miss or TLB hit?

Comment: Sorry. I mean TLB Hit

Comment: A TLB hit and a page fault, should lead to some erroneous situation, which we normally assume wouldn't happen, unless and until specified, and i think this made clear by @arjun suresh in https://www.facebook.com/groups/core.cs/permalink/528411797191078/?stream_ref=2

Comment: You have 0.1*150 as the term for each TLB miss. Shouldn't it be 0.1*300 instead since the page table is 2 level? (Two memory references needed)

Comment: Few doubts here: 1. The formula for Effective access time says if there is a TLB hit, we add TLB lookup time with memory access time and multiply it with TLB hit ratio. You haven't done that here. Why? 2. You wrote yourself that since the page table is 2 level, we need 2 memory accesses, yet you did `0.1*150` instead of `0.1*(150+150)`. 3. Where is this `20000` coming from? the question says `10000` instructions.

Comment: 1) two level pages so shouldn't it be 2*150.   2) Where is this 20000 coming from? the question says 10000 instructions.   3) Why is 8ms taken 8 x 10^6, isn't it 8 x 10^-3